# How to get code in inspect element using C# (Windows form)?

Tags: c#, html, browser, element, inspect

Hello guys i start a statistics program with C#, and for that i want a value from a website, the value appear in inspect but not in html code ,
for that, how can i get all the inspect element code in string with C#,
Anyone can help me ?
and thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a WebClient instance, then use it to download the string to your website :)

Example: `textBox1.Text = new WebClient().DownloadString(new Uri("http://www.google.co.uk"));`

Comment: That's the problem i do it but it give just the Html code :/

Comment: I don;t understand your question then, you want to make inspect element in a program?

Comment: i want inspect element code not html code, for what do you tell me Webclient and downloadString get only HTML :(

Comment: he wants the parsed javascript applied code.  the html code you see (when you press ctrl u  or  f12)  is DİFFERENT than  when you do  rightClick>inspectElement   on a webpage in chrome. that is what he is trying to say. and he is right its different in %50 of webpages. this may be because of javascript appends some codes\tags\texts after html document is ready/loaded.

Comment: open it with c# webbrowser  control.   navigeto that file or url  by webbrowser.navige(url) .   from now on you have to get parsed html . but how ? that is i dont know too